# Where does Asch the Bloody fit in the timeline of Tales of the Abyss?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

I got the limited edition of the first volume of the anime, which came with "Asch the Bloody" manga. I figure it's mainly about Ache, but I'm wondering when the story took place relative to the main series. Did it take place during the 6 years he was with Van, or did it occur in the same period as in the anime/game?

Comment: You meant Asch, right? It's just side story.

Comment: @Krazer oh yeh, by bad